# Find coordinate of each centroid along with cluster in Kmeans

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to determine cluster and coordinate of each cluster's centroid for every data point. Currently, I am able to get both of them separately using the below scripts

```
#This gives cluster for each data point
y  = np.array(x)
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=32932)
kmeans_predict = kmeans_model.fit_predict(y)
kmeans_predict

#This gives coordinate of each cluster
a = kmeans_model.cluster_centers_
df_Centroid =pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['x','y'])
```

Is there a way in `df_Centroid` I can add the which cluster the coordinate is?

Comment: You need `kmeans_model.labels_`

Comment: @ Mechanic Pig this just gives me clusters of each data point. What I want is Cluster and Coordinate of Centroid, i.e. 0, x, y where 0 is the cluster and x,y are coordinate of centroid.